# Как правильно закрыть соединение в netty?

Tags: java, netty

Создаю свое клиент-серверное приложение, изучая попутно netty. 
Как отловить сервером событие закрытия канала клиентом?
При аварийном или принудительном закрытии программы на стороне клиента сервер знает об этом, и выдает такой лог:

```
java.io.IOException: Соединение разорвано другой стороной
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:349)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:112)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:571)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:512)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:426)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:398)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:805)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:145)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Но если закрыть со стороны клиента методом `ch.close(),ch.closeFuture().sync();`, то ничего не происходит. Как правильно отследить подобное событие?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там можно повесить листенер на `ChannelFuture`:

```
ChannelFuture closeFuture = channel.closeFuture();

   closeFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {

        }
    });
```

Comment: В моем Handler-e сервера в метод channelRead0 добавил данную строчку по примеру [ссылка] (https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html). Теперь при подключении клиента канал автоматически закрывается. Что именно я делаю не правильно?
'ChannelFuture f = ctx.channel().closeFuture();
                            f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                                    //делаем что-то

                                }
                            });'

Comment: @Killersssurprise Т.е если убрать `addListener`, то все работает?

Comment: Ну, если убрать всю эту конструкцию - то работает как и прежде. Сам метод ctx.channel().closeFuture() закрывает канал, как я подозреваю. Так что когда мы определяем ChannelFuture f = ctx.channel().closeFuture(); - мы автоматических закрываем канал?

Comment: @Killersssurprise нет, closeFuture() не закрывает канал, а только возвращает футуру по которой мы следим за событиями. Так что это не должно влиять.

Comment: В тогда чем еще может быть ошибка?

Comment: Не знаю. В чем-то еще. Накидал код сервера, где все ок. Только я вешаю листенер не в channelRead0, а то листенеры накапливаются. а когда канал активируется http://pastebin.com/msbHgzQ3 Вешать листенер можно и в самом `ChannelInitializer::initChannel`

Comment: Да, проблема была как раз в том, что я в ChannelRead0 закинул код, хотя сразу необходимо было в ChannelActive.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону периодического пинга клиентов. В нетти есть инструменты для этого [IdleStateHandler](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html)

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(timer, 0, 0));

}
```

Comment: Cпасибо, как раз подобное я и искал.